# Display a specific image from assets

Tags: templating, assets, image

I'm trying to grab a specific image to display that is located in assets. I tried using `{% set image = craft.assets.filename('image_filename.jpg') %}` but I get the error "An unknown image object was used." I also tried referring to one of the asset sources which I saw as a solution in another post related to my question: `{% set image = craft.assets.source('my_images') %}` but I'm not sure how that would help me grab a specific image. `{% set image = craft.assets.images[0] %}` just grabs an image from any of the asset sources if I change the index number. What am I doing wrong here?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
 {% image = craft.assets.id(x).first() %}
```

Where x is the ID of your element. You can see the ids of your elements in your cp. There is a little wheel icon below your asset sources where you can define which attributes to display. Just check the selectbox for id

You can learn more about fetching entries with `ElementCriteriaModels` in the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax)

Your problem was: you did not fetch the element. You prepared your database query but you need to execute it with `first()` or `find()` because

Comment: I was just about to update this post saying that I figured out the solution with this very same method. Glad to know I did it right. Thanks!

Comment: 2020, `.first()` is deprecated for `.one()`